# Pass the PID from tasklist into taskkill to kill a process by the .dlls it's holding open

Tags: windows, batch-file

Windows scripting noob here. Say I've got the name of a .dll I need to delete or copy over, and I'm getting the classic "The file is in use by another process..." error. I know I can run tasklist with the /m switch and pass it the dll name. Then I can get the PID for the processes and kill them with taskkill.

How can I do this in one step in a batch file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reminder: in a batch file you will need to use the double "%%" instead a single

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 skip=2" %i IN (`tasklist /m winsta.dll`) DO taskkill /PID %i
```

Comment: be aware that "skip=2" means to skip the first two lines of output, in case you want to tweak this (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712399/pass-pids-from-tasklist-and-kill-processes-with-tasklist)

Answer (score 1):

> FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 skip=2" %%i IN (`TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq
>   tomcat6.exe"`) DO taskkill /F /PID %%i

will automatically kill the tomcat process.

Answer (score 0):

Goyuix,

I can't seem to get the tasklist results to parse.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 skip=2" %i IN ('tasklist /m winsta.dll') DO echo %i
The tasklist command by itself is fine, but the loop is not recognizing the tasklist resuls.  Rather it appears to be parsing the string.  I can output the task list results to file and parse with the loop, but I thought I might be missing something simple.

Comment: use a backtick (same key as the tilde on most U.S. layout keyboards) - not the single quote. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

yep.  simple.  backquote, not single quote.