# Pass PIDs from tasklist and kill processes with tasklist WITH spaces in the name of the process

Tags: windows, process, batch-file, batch

So this question is VERY similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/369863/480190), with [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/370209/480190). But some of my processes have a space in the name, and CMD returns nothing. My original question has been answered in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/370209/480190), **this question** is asking how would I do this, but with spaces in the process name.

Code so far:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-10" %%i IN (`tasklist ^|findstr /b "nvsphelper64.exe"`) DO taskkill /F /PID %%j
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-10" %%i IN (`tasklist ^|findstr /b "nvcontainer.exe"`) DO taskkill /F /PID %%j
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-10" %%i IN (`tasklist ^|findstr /b "NVIDIA Share.exe"`) DO taskkill /F /PID %%j
pause
```

I already tried putting `'` around `NVIDIA Share.exe`, and I also tried putting `"` around it as well, but it still ignores that line when executing.

(I have tried executing as a 32bit exe as admin, and as batch as admin and without admin, but to no avail.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some misunderstandings how `for /f` works in combination with normal tasklist output and findstr.

```
> tasklist

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0          8 K
System                           4 Services                   0      4.896 K
...snip...
```

The default `For /f` delimiter is the space and you don't change that.
Consecutive delimiters are counted as one and leading ones are ignored.
So to get the PID in the line `System Idle Process` you have to address token 4, in the next line `System` the PID is token 2.

Findstr OTOH works in RegEx mode by default which means the search words seperated by space are `OR`ed - each one matches independently. To overcome this either exchange the space between `NVIDIA Share.exe` with a dot meaning any character - or switch to `/C:"NVIDIA Share.exe"` to match literally. (to exactly match a literal dot in RegEx you have to escape it with a backslash.

So this should work for you:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%A IN ('tasklist ^|findstr /b "nvsphelper64\.exe" ') DO taskkill /F /PID %%A
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%A IN ('tasklist ^|findstr /b "nvcontainer\.exe"  ') DO taskkill /F /PID %%A
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('tasklist ^|findstr /b "NVIDIA.Share\.exe" ') DO taskkill /F /PID %%A
pause
```